# Installing PECL on MAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl, osx-mavericks

I have began installing `pecl` on MAMP. I have added the correct php version to the path and when `which php` it says /Applications/MAMP/... which is correct.

I have downloaded the `Server Components and libraries` moved them to a new folder in my php and run the `./configure` everything seems to run ok and looked through all the checks being performed while installing and unpacking.

It gets to the last line and says;

```
configure: error: Please specify the install prefix of iconv with --with-iconv=<DIR>
```

Where should I set the `<DIR>` for the iconv?

Just make another folder and point it at that?

I am only trying to get the mongo pecl installed.

The information I have followed is here http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-mamp-mac-os-x-107-lion

Comment: I am having the same problem following the same essential steps.  I don't know what to set the <DIR> to.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working on this right now and found a workaround to just disable iconv with `./configure --without-iconv` which not the best solution of course, but works for me.

Edit: Downloaded libiconv-1.14 package, and after running ./configure , make, make install, PHP configure runs fine.

Comment: Would I extract this `libiconv` in the same include folder and make it in there? After running the `configure` it went through all ok. But where do I extract the libiconv?  Thank you

Comment: @StudentRik the place to extract `libiconv` doesn't matter, as you install it with `make install` and once it is installed PHP configure script sees it.

Answer (score 7):

Wait wait wait wait. Why are you rebuilding your PHP installation to install the MongoDB driver?

You don't have to do that.

Just run e.g.:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/bin/pecl install mongo
```

Assuming thats the full path to the `pecl` command part of your MAMP installation.
You might need to replace `/php7.1.1/` with your current and active MAMP php version.

Comment: This is the very simplest way to install pecl pacakages. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me:

```
$ ./configure --with-iconv=/usr/lib/
```

First needed to install libxml2 and libxslt via homebrew though:

```
$ brew install libxml2
$ brew install libxslt
```

Comment: Most importantly is to run `$ brew install libiconv` and then `./configure --with-iconv=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1`.